# Horizontal scroll not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, horizontal-scrolling

I have a website with horizontal scroll. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

http://jellekok.com/customers/udiverse/

Any idea why it's not working in Chrome?

Main JS file: jquery1.8.2.min.js

horizontal scroll javascript:

```
/* jQuery.ScrollTo - Easy element scrolling using jQuery - Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com - Dual licensed under MIT and GPL - Date: 3/9/2009 - @author Ariel Flesler - @version 1.4.1 - http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html */
```

;(function($){var m=$.scrollTo=function(b,h,f){$(window).scrollTo(b,h,f)};m.defaults={axis:'xy',duration:parseFloat($.fn.jquery)>=1.3?0:1};m.window=function(b){return $(window).scrollable()};$.fn.scrollable=function(){return this.map(function(){var b=this,h=!b.nodeName||$.inArray(b.nodeName.toLowerCase(),['iframe','#document','html','body'])!=-1;if(!h)return b;var f=(b.contentWindow||b).document||b.ownerDocument||b;return $.browser.safari||f.compatMode=='BackCompat'?f.body:f.documentElement})};$.fn.scrollTo=function(l,j,a){if(typeof j=='object'){a=j;j=0}if(typeof a=='function')a={onAfter:a};if(l=='max')l=9e9;a=$.extend({},m.defaults,a);j=j||a.speed||a.duration;a.queue=a.queue&&a.axis.length>1;if(a.queue)j/=2;a.offset=n(a.offset);a.over=n(a.over);return this.scrollable().each(function(){var k=this,o=$(k),d=l,p,g={},q=o.is('html,body');switch(typeof d){case'number':case'string':if(/^([+-]=)?\d+(.\d+)?(px)?$/.test(d)){d=n(d);break}d=$(d,this);case'object':if(d.is||d.style)p=(d=$(d)).offset()}$.each(a.axis.split(''),function(b,h){var f=h=='x'?'Left':'Top',i=f.toLowerCase(),c='scroll'+f,r=k[c],s=h=='x'?'Width':'Height';if(p){g[c]=p[i]+(q?0:r-o.offset()[i]);if(a.margin){g[c]-=parseInt(d.css('margin'+f))||0;g[c]-=parseInt(d.css('border'+f+'Width'))||0}g[c]+=a.offset[i]||0;if(a.over[i])g[c]+=ds.toLowerCase()*a.over[i]}else g[c]=d[i];if(/^\d+$/.test(g[c]))g[c]=g[c]<=0?0:Math.min(g[c],u(s));if(!b&&a.queue){if(r!=g[c])t(a.onAfterFirst);delete g[c]}});t(a.onAfter);function t(b){o.animate(g,j,a.easing,b&&function(){b.call(this,l,a)})};function u(b){var h='scroll'+b;if(!q)return k[h];var f='client'+b,i=k.ownerDocument.documentElement,c=k.ownerDocument.body;return Math.max(i[h],c[h])-Math.min(i[f],c[f])}}).end()};function n(b){return typeof b=='object'?b:{top:b,left:b}}})(jQuery);

/* jQuery.LocalScroll - Animated scrolling navigation, using anchors - Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Ariel Flesler - aflesler(at)gmail(dot)com | http://flesler.blogspot.com - Dual licensed under MIT and GPL - Date: 3/11/2009 - @author Ariel Flesler - @version 1.2.7 */
;(function($){var l=location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');var g=$.localScroll=function(a){$('body').localScroll(a)};g.defaults={duration:1e3,axis:'y',event:'click',stop:true,target:window,reset:true};g.hash=function(a){if(location.hash){a=$.extend({},g.defaults,a);a.hash=false;if(a.reset){var e=a.duration;delete a.duration;$(a.target).scrollTo(0,a);a.duration=e}i(0,location,a)}};$.fn.localScroll=function(b){b=$.extend({},g.defaults,b);return b.lazy?this.bind(b.event,function(a){var e=$([a.target,a.target.parentNode]).filter(d)[0];if(e)i(a,e,b)}):this.find('a,area').filter(d).bind(b.event,function(a){i(a,this,b)}).end().end();function d(){return!!this.href&&!!this.hash&&this.href.replace(this.hash,'')==l&&(!b.filter||$(this).is(b.filter))}};function i(a,e,b){var d=e.hash.slice(1),f=document.getElementById(d)||document.getElementsByName(d)[0];if(!f)return;if(a)a.preventDefault();var h=$(b.target);if(b.lock&&h.is(':animated')||b.onBefore&&b.onBefore.call(b,a,f,h)===false)return;if(b.stop)h.stop(true);if(b.hash){var j=f.id==d?'id':'name',k=$(' ').attr(j,d).css({position:'absolute',top:$(window).scrollTop(),left:$(window).scrollLeft()});f[j]='';$('body').prepend(k);location=e.hash;k.remove();f[j]=d}h.scrollTo(f,b).trigger('notify.serialScroll',[f])}})(jQuery);

/* Fire Horizontal Scroll */
$(document).ready(function () {$.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x'; $.localScroll(); });

This is the html for the sliding divs:

```
<div id="one">
            <div class="content">
                <ul class="bxslider">
                  <li><img src="img/coaching.jpg" title="" /></li>
                  <li><img src="img/girl_1.jpg" title="" /><span>"Magali is helpful, devoted and really involved in your success. Furthermore, she is a truly devoted person. She's not only a career coach but she is also personally involved and committed to the person she is working with."</span></li>
                  <li><img src="img/boy_1.jpg" title="" /><span>"Magali is very flexible with her clients and fully immerses herself in the desire to get to the core of your career needs. She is very organized with a positive outlook. Magali helped me find answers to some of the fundamental questions I had regarding my professional journey."</span></li>         
                  <li><img src="img/girl_2.jpg" title="" /><span>"Magali is an efficient and dedicated person who has helped me improve my CV and solicitation letters. She was very helpful when advising me on how to improve my interview skills."</span></li>
                  <li><img src="img/boy_2.jpg" title="" /><span>"Magali has been my career coach and adviser since last summer when I was lost in my professional orientation and I couldn't seem to succeed in job interviews anymore. She helped me to be confident again and after only one month I found a job and some new professional goals!"</span></li>
                  <li><img src="img/cheers.jpg" title="" /><a href="#eight" class="gtk">Schedule your <br />'Get to know' session</a></li>
                </ul>

                <h1>Career and Cross-Cultural Coaching<br /> for Expatriates and International Workers</h1>
                <h2>"Diversify your unique career"</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>You are unaware of your strengths and what you should do for a living</li>
                    <li>You live abroad and you are now stuck in your career</li>
                    <li>You are unsure how to begin your job search and feel disoriented in an unfamiliar culture</li>
                    <li>You experience culture shock, you are uncertain on how to prepare for your relocation or have issues adapting to other cultures</li>
                </ul>
                <br />
                U Diverse helps you explore your dream career, hunt for your ideal job, successfully advance in your career and adapt seamlessly to a new culture.
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <a href="#two" class="next">><br />You are..</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>You are..</h1>
            <h2>"Uniquely diverse"</h2>
            <ul id="job_types">
                <li><img src="img/explorer.jpg" alt="" /><br />Explorer<span>You are unclear about the next step of your career and would like to explore<br /> different options.</span></li>
                <li><img src="img/conqueror.jpg" alt="" /><br />Conqueror<span>You are clear about the next steps of your career and you are now looking for the right opportunity.</span></li>
                <li><img src="img/hunter.jpg" alt="" /><br />Hunter<span>You are in the right career opportunity and you want to improve your satisfaction level and advance your career.</span></li>
                <li><img src="img/nomad.jpg" alt="" /><br />Global Nomad<span>You plan to work abroad or have moved abroad and need help transitioning into a new culture.</span></li>
            </ul>
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#three" class="next alt">><br />Explore..</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to provide the minimum code required to duplicate the issue instead of pointing us to a link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works in chrome but not in firefox. In js file jquery1.8.2.min it uses getPreventDefault() this function is automatically deprecated by the firefox browser but not in chrome so that's why you had horizontal scroll in the firefox browser. Inspect the site in the both browsers and check the console.

Comment: is it not possible to turn this function off, so it works in chrome too?

Comment: @Jelle add the latest version of jquery file like 1.11`

Comment: when i add 1.11 instead of 1.8.2 it doesn't work in firefox too. and with another website it also works with this version of jquery..

Comment: @Jelle Because it is prevent the default page.you need to script to avoid from prevent default page function

Comment: hmm, i don't know how to do that.
the strange thing, i have the same script working here in chrome and firefox: http://jellekok.com/customers/vispo/v2/

Comment: @Jelle I think you used same id for two sliders try to implement horizontal with using class rather than id

Comment: i now got it working in chrome, by using jquery v1.3.2 + removing the other content slider.
now i guess i have to find a slider that doesn't conflict and works with this jquery version

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by using both the jquery files for the script (1.3.2 and 1.8.2) and using the noconflict option: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp